# callback on object method C++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, callback

I would like to create a callback for this function prototype :
`Timer_Install(int, void (*)(), int);`

So far, I tried to use a lambda function with `std=c++11`

```
auto receive = [this](){receptMessage();}; // pointer on this->receptMessage();
Timer_Install(0, receive, 1);
```

Wich result in the following error :

> error : canot convert 'Obj::method::' to 'void(*)()'

I have also tried various things like :

```
void (*ptrReception)();
ptrReception = this->receptMessage;
Timer_Instal(0, ptrReception, 1);
```

> error : cannot convert 'Obj::method' from type 'void(Obj::)()' to type
>   'void(*)()'

Is there anyway to get this working ?

Comment: Capturing lamdas cannot be converted into function pointers. There must be a duplicate somewhere....

Comment: There must be hundreds of duplicates of this question by now.

Comment: Do your timer-API allow you to pass some kind of user-data? Perhaps a pointer? Then you can use that pointer for the object instance (i.e. `this`) and use a static member function that takes the pointer and call the real function in the object. Otherwise it's really not possible, what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, there is no way to pass user-data.

Comment: Then you have to think of another way. By the way, what does the two `int` arguments mean? Can't they be used in some way to map to an object? Maybe you should try and find some other timer API that is more compatible with C++ code?

Comment: @Rakete1111 This is more a question about _what i have tried so far_ than a real question about how to convert lambda to function pointer

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Not possible, as I'm already using a sycall.

Comment: @Xavier59 Yeah, I would've used another question as duplicate too, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: @Rakete1111 So maybe it is not one ....